# How can I use time in Java to manipulate code?

Tags: java, time

I'm trying to test the use of time in Java to manipulate code. So let's say I have a app with an egg. The egg won't hatch until 60 seconds have passed in the application, what method or class would I use to do this?

Comment: Please try to elaborate on your question; I'm pretty sure there's no Java API to alter physics.

Comment: You can use date? System.CurrentTimeMilis. There is countless of ways. Just google of a way to get time on java, and Google ways to do addition and subtraction on the date.

Comment: Maybe you can subclass [java.util.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and create an `EggTimer`?

Comment: You probably want a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) if you want to do something at a scheduled time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class should do what you are after:

> A facility for threads to schedule tasks for future execution in a background thread. Tasks 
>   may be scheduled for one-time execution, or for repeated execution at
>   regular intervals.

You can take a look at a simple example available [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jdk-timer-scheduler-example/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use timer in a way like this

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
```

If you want your code to run multiple times:

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // Your logic here 
    // Your logic will run every 60 second
    System.out.println("egg hatched");
  }
}, 0, 60000);
```

If you want it to run only one time

```
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // Your logic here
    System.out.println("egg hatched");
  }
}, 60000);
```

You can read more about class timer in java [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest old-fashioned single thread approach is

```
    Thread.sleep(60*1000);
    System.out.println("egg hatched");
```

And there is no guaranty that it print **exactly** after minute

Answer (score 0):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` returns the current time of the system in milliseconds to your. So you need to create a `Thread` checking for the current time in a `while` loop an react to it.

Comment: Busy-waiting is usually an anti-pattern.

Comment: Why reimplement [the wheel](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Timer.java)?

Answer (score 0):

Try run it it a separate scheduled thread;

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
                Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        Runnable hatcher = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                egg.hatch();
            }
        };
        scheduler.schedule(hatcher, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```